# Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor

Tags: boot, uefi, 21.04

Every time I try to boot, I get the following:

[0.011411] efi: Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor for 0x000000007c8fa000

[0.135602] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS

/dev/sda2: clean, 274720/29278208 files, 6863063/117081344 blocks

[3.871420]

(after this, it's the emergency mode message which I won't bother typing)

Pressing Ctrl+D or typing exit causes the system to display the following lines then start emergency mode again after a few minutes:

Reloading system manager configuration

Starting default target

I started having this issue after I used GParted to move and resize a partition on a drive (not the one Ubuntu was installed on). At the time, I did get a warning telling me I may be unable to boot after doing this. I thought I would be fine considering it was on another drive, however, and ignored it. I was, of course, wrong. I'm not sure if this is related, as the terminal does not mention this drive at all, but it's the last major operation I did. I'm running Ubuntu 21.04, secure boot is disabled, and this is not a LiveUSB, if that helps.

Comment: The partition you messed with was by any chance the ESP (EFI System Partition)? If not, what exactly was that partition?

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's a partition on a different drive altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had an entry in my fstab for a partition that didn't exist (the one that I altered). If anyone else is having this issue, get a liveUSB and boot from it, find the partition that Ubuntu is installed on, do "sudo gedit (insert path to partition here)/etc/fstab" and remove any entries that list UUIDs unable to be found in the Disks application.